# Compare Image with Array

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on a website that provides a variety of services to the general public. I have product information in a MySQL database and product images stored in separate image folders.  Now I create a product page I retrieve all information from database successfully. Every product has a specific id and his image is same name with product id. How to retrieve product image that match with product id.
My PHP Codes:

```
$id = $_SESSION[‘company_id’];

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT  product_id FROM product_s WHERE product_id LIKE '$id%'");

while($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){
    $image = $result['product_id'].'.jpg';
}

$location = '../../images/companies/'.$_SESSION['company_id'].'/products/';

$img = scandir($location);

$result_image = in_array($image, $img);

echo’<img src=” ’.$location.’/’.$result_image.’ ” alt=”$result_image”>’;
```

But it does not work.

Comment: Looking past all the security holes here... `$image = $result['product_id'].'.jpg';` should be `$image[] = $result['product_id'].'.jpg';` for starters.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
$id = $_SESSION['company_id'];
$location = '../../images/companies/'.$id.'/products/';

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT product_id FROM product_s WHERE product_id LIKE '$id%'");

while($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){
    $image = $result['product_id'];
    echo '<img src="'.$location.'/'.$image.'.jpg" alt="$image">;
}
```

Here is another method you can use, that will do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you want something like this:

```
while($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){

    $imagePath ='./../images/companies/'.$_SESSION['company_id'].'/products/' . $result['product_id'] . 'jpg';

    if (is_readable($imagePath)) {
        echo '<img src="' . $imagePath . " alt="$result['product_id'] . '.jpg'">;
    }

}
```